# Any example of `cholmod_updown_solve()` (Updating in CHOLMOD)?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, suitesparse

I'm working on a project using CHOLMOD in C++ to do Cholesky factorization updating. The only reference I can find is the User Guide. And `cholmod_updown_solve()` seems to be the right function for me. But there is no example on this function and I can't get a correct result.

Below is the essential part of my code. According to the user guide, the only thing to notice seems to be sorting the update matrix `C` in advance. But that doesn't work. Could anyone tell me if there's any important step I missed?

Also, I'm confused because the user guide says that the solution `phi` will be given "in the permuted ordering, not your original ordering". How could I restore the order without knowing the permutation matrix? (`L->Perm` doesn't work.)

```
// The original system is At*A*phi = At*b
// Updates: C*Ct is added to At*A (Here C is a sparse column vector)

size_t n = m_pMesh->numVertices();
double w = 1e3;

cholmod_sparse *C;
cholmod_triplet *C_coefficients;
cholmod_dense *Delta_Atb;

cholmod_common common;
cholmod_common *cm = &common;
cholmod_start(cm);

C_coefficients = cholmod_allocate_triplet(n, 1, 2, 0, CHOLMOD_REAL, cm);
Delta_Atb = cholmod_zeros(n, 1, CHOLMOD_REAL, cm);

// updates: two more constraints
CViewerVertex *pNew = stroke_ends.start;
CViewerVertex *qNew = stroke_ends.end;
cholmodEntry(C_coefficients, pNew->sid(), pNew->sid(), w, cm);
cholmodEntry(C_coefficients, qNew->sid(), qNew->sid(), w, cm);

// change to At*b is Delta_Atb
((double*)Delta_Atb->x)[pNew->sid()] = w * w;

C = cholmod_triplet_to_sparse(C_coefficients, C_coefficients->nnz, cm);
cholmod_sort(C, cm);

// phi is the given solution to the original system At*A*phi = At*b
// L is the Cholesky factor to modify
// Both phi and L should be overwritten here
cholmod_updown_solve(1, C, L, phi, Delta_Atb, cm);

cholmod_free_sparse(&C, cm);
cholmod_free_triplet(&C_coefficients, cm);
cholmod_free_dense(&Delta_Atb, cm);

cholmod_finish(cm);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had several issues in getting a correct implementation using `cholmod_updown_solve()`. First of all, it might help understanding what the advantage of using this function is. A typical implementation using `cholmod_updown()` will look like this:

```
cholmod_updown(update, C, L, cm);
cholmod_dense *x = cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_A, L, b, cm);
```

Running `cholmod_solve()` for the system `CHOLMOD_A` will run both the forward and backward subsitution algorithms, each requiring `2nnz(L)` float point operations.

Alternatively, you can compute an initial solution to the `Ly=Pb` system as follows and reuse it later:

```
cholmod_dense *Pb = cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_P, L, b, cm);
cholmod_dense *y = cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_L, L, Pb, cm);
cholmod_dense *zeros = cholmod_zeros(L->n, 1, CHOLMOD_REAL, cm);
...
cholmod_updown_solve(update, C, L, y, zeros, cm);
cholmod_dense *Px = cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_DLt, L, y, cm);
cholmod_dense *x = cholmod_solve(CHOLMOD_Pt, L, Px, cm);
```

This will be faster as `cholmod_solve()` for the system `CHOLMOD_DLt` will only run the backward substitution algorithm so if your update changes a small number of the columns of `L` you could get a speed improvement of almost 2x.

You have to be careful though, as `cholmod_updown_solve()` will convert any supernodal or `LL'` factorization into a simplicial `LDL'` factorization so before you initialize a solution for `Ly=Pb` you need to make sure you are working with an `LDL'` factorization. This can be achieved by running:

```
if (L->is_super || L->is_ll) cholmod_change_factor(CHOLMOD_REAL, 0, 0, 0, 0, L, cm);
```

before calling `cholmod_solve()` to initialize a solution to the `Ly=Pb` system.

As for constructing the update sparse matrix `C` to your matrix `A=P'LDL'P`, as explained in the [source code](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/SuiteSparse/blob/dev/CHOLMOD/Modify/cholmod_updown.c), you have to actually provide `cholmod_updown()` or `cholmod_updown_solve()` with the sparse matrix `PC` which can be generated with the command:

```
cholmod sparse *PC = cholmod_submatrix(C, L->Perm, L->n, NULL, -1, 1, 1, cm);
```

Alternatively you can build an inverse permutation array:

```
int *IPerm = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * L->n);
for (int i = 0; i < L->n; i++) IPerm[((int *)L->Perm)[i]] = i;
```

And then update the row indexes of `C` using `IPerm`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < C->nzmax; i++) ((int *)C->i)[i] = IPerm[((int *)C->i)[i]];
```